# Mock ApolloClient's query(call) for testing purposes

Tags: android, kotlin, graphql, apollo-client, graphql-java

Kotlin Android app using graphQl & ApolloClient.

I want to test this method:

```
fun myMethod(id: String): Single<List<MyEntity>> {
    val call = Query(id)
    return Rx2Apollo.from(apolloClient.query(call))
      .map { modeCode() }.firstOrError().onErrorReturn { emptyList() }
  }
```

Is there an elegant way to mock the response of `apolloClient.query(call)` so Rx2Apollo returns the response?

I tried with a RealApolloCall, with a custom ApolloCall, etc, nothing convinces me.
And I wouldn't want to extract and mock the whole `Rx2Apollo.from(apolloClient.query(call))` part. To use mockWebServer doesn't apply, because I do not want to test apolloClient, I want to mock its response to test the rest.

There is a related issue that was closed without really mentioning the best way to solve:
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android/issues/1144

Thanks!

Comment: Did you find how to mock it?? if yes please share with us

Comment: I went with a helper wrapper for now, smth like:
```
  fun getWrapped(id: Long, objectTypeId: String): Observable<Data?>? {
    val call = Query(
      id = id,
      type = objectTypeId
    )
    return Rx2Apollo.from(apolloClient.query(call)).map { res -> res.data }
  }

```
then you can test all modifiers, mappers, converters on top of Observable<Data>